# Is there (a -> b) -> ((Maybe a) -> (Maybe b)) converter in standard library?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm just learning Haskell and I found myself writing this piece of code for homework assignment:

```
eval :: ExprT -> Integer
eval (Lit x)    = x
eval (Add x y)  = (eval x) + (eval y)
eval (Mul x y)  = (eval x) * (eval y)

evalMayBe :: Maybe ExprT -> Maybe Integer
evalMayBe Nothing   = Nothing
evalMayBe (Just x)  = Just (eval x)
```

The second function seemed a bit redundant, so I wrote a converter:

```
toMayBe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
toMayBe _ Nothing   = Nothing
toMayBe f (Just x)  = Just (f x)
```

And rewrote the function just as

```
evalMayBe :: Maybe ExprT -> Maybe Integer
evalMayBe = toMayBe eval
```

But then I thought that this converter seemed to be so useful for so many different situations that it must be in the standard library somewhere - however, I wasn't able to find it.

Is it in the standard library? And what is the "right" way to write code like this, where you must chain a function on values in a chain where these values might be a Maybe?

Comment: That's simply `fmap`, using the standard `Functor` instance for `Maybe`. (See  http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass for a good introduction, including the `Maybe` instance.) So yes, it's an integral part of the standard library.

Comment: It's unfortunate @RobinZigmond's comment is being upvoted, because it's a terrible comment.  On the other hand it's a good **ANSWER**, so maybe it should have been entered down below, where **ANSWERS** go.  Seriously, comments are for seeking clarification.  Answering questions in the comments leaves a bunch of half-open questions around that diminish the value of the site.  If you don't think a question warrants a real answer, then **don't answer it.**  Let someone else do it.  If you have an answer, treat it as a real answer and put it where answers belong.

Comment: Sorry @K.A.Buhr, I tend to comment rather than answer if it's something I can say quickly, particularly when I'm pushed for time (was watching over the kids at a party, while browsing SO on my mobile). I view quick simple things like this as more worthy of comments than full answers, which would give me reputation that I consider not really deserved (as almost anyone else reading this would be capable of giving the same answer).

Comment: But I'm still relatively new to contributing on SO, if there's some rule that says things like this have to be an answer, I'll try to do that in future.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, note the instructions that appear in a comment box when you start writing a comment:  "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.  Avoid answering questions in comments."  It's also been discussed in Meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments).  If you feel bad getting "undeserved rep", then leave the question for a low-rep user to answer!

Comment: ...like @DanielWagner.  He's been trying to find a question simple enough for him to answer for years! ;)

Comment: @K.A.Buhr ...and I think I may have finally found one! =D That said, I'm as guilty as any of occasionally answering in the comments. It's incredibly tempting, especially when the answer is one word long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is `fmap`. You can discover this kind of thing for yourself in the future by dumping the type of your function [into Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+->+b%29+->+Maybe+a+->+Maybe+b), which gives `fmap` as its first result for your proposed type.